# IOS6 build link error

Tags: objective-c, ios

I build my app link with a static lib,found the errors follow

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"std::_List_node_base::hook(std::_List_node_base*)", referenced from:
      std::list<TSendBuf, std::allocator<TSendBuf> >::_M_insert(std::_List_iterator<TSendBuf>, TSendBuf const&) in libCardAnalyLib1.a(SendRecvThread.o)
"std::_List_node_base::unhook()", referenced from:
      std::list<TSendBuf, std::allocator<TSendBuf> >::_M_erase(std::_List_iterator<TSendBuf>) in libCardAnalyLib1.a(SendRecvThread.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can anyone tell me what is this error? thank you.
  And there is C++ code in the app and the lib.
  my demo app can not link the lib,  shows this error, and the TSendBuf is

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char szBuf[1200];//1000 fah  char
} TSendBuf;
```

Comment: Has the library been built for the amr7 architecture?

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to add `libstdc++.dylib` to the list of frameworks/binaries your application links to.

You can do that from target settings / "Build Phases" tab / "Link binary with Libraries" section

Answer (score 2):

Library and app possibly do not match in link-settings.

Check specifically for the the **C++ Standard Library** setting, under **Apple LLVM compiler** within the Xcode **Build Settings** of both, your library and your app. Those need to match.

Supposed that the library in question is nothing you are building yourself, and if that library was built some time ago (pre Xcode 4.5/LLVM 4.1), then the "correct" setting for your app would be **libstdc++ (GNU C++ standard library)**.